# sizeof operator in C behavior with strings

Tags: c, sizeof, c99

For the **sizeof** operator I am seeing following results; and I am not able understand the reason behind the same.
What I understand is **sizeof** operator returns the result in terms of **size_t**
Below are the results,

```
sizeof("6") -> 2
sizeof("a") -> 2
sizeof('a') -> 4
sizeof("something") -> 10
sizeof("some") -> 5
```

Comment: And what about these results confuses you?

Answer (score 7):

By definition ([C11 3.6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.6)), 1 char requires 1 byte (may not be 1 octet in some exotic system)

`"6"` has type `char[2]`, so 2 bytes
`"a"` has type `char[2]`
`'a'` has type `int` ==> in your system, `int` requires 4 bytes
`"something"` has type `char[10]`
`"some"` has type `char[5]`

Note that `"a"` and `'a'` are very different things: `"a"` is an array of `char` with 2 elements; `'a'` is an `int` value, very much like `42` or `-1`.

Comment: To further elaborate, the primary difference is the usage of `"` versus `'` for defining C-strings versus a single char/int.

Answer (score 1):

In records like this

```
sizeof("6") -> 2
```

there is used a string literal as an operand.

String literals are character arrays that store a sequence of characters terminated with the zero character `'\0'`.

So for example the string literal `"6"` is stored in memory like

```
char literal_6[] = { '6', '\0' };
```

Or this declaration is equivalent to

```
char literal_6[2] = { '6', '\0' };
```

Note: for example the string literal "some" is stored in memory like a character array declared as

```
char literal_some[] = { 's', 'o', 'm', 'e', '\0' };
```

So the expression `sizeof("6")` is equivalent to the expression `sizeof( char[2] )`.

In this record

```
sizeof('a') -> 4
```

there is used integer character constant `'4'` that has the type `int`.

So this expression `sizeof('a')` is equivalent to the expression `sizeof( int )`.

It is interesting to note that for example `sizeof("something")` is not equal to `sizeof("something" + 0)`. In the last expression the character array that denotes the string literal is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So the last expression is equivalent to the expression `sizeof( char * )`.

Also pay attention to that if you have for example

```
int x = 10;
size_t n = sizeof( ++x );
```

then `x` will not be equal to `11` after the declaration of `n` because in this case the expression used as an operand of the `sizeof` operator is not evaluated. It is only the type of the expression that is important.

On the other hand if you have a variable length array then the operator `sizeof` will evaluate at run-time to determine its size. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    for ( int i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        int a[i];
        printf( "sizeof( a[%d] ) = %zu\n", i, sizeof( a ) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( a[1] ) = 4
sizeof( a[2] ) = 8
sizeof( a[3] ) = 12
sizeof( a[4] ) = 16
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for the acute explanation with examples